# Active Directory Web Services (ADWS) SDK

Tags: wcf, soap, active-directory

I recently come to know that there are web services by WCF for Active Directory. I presume this is not about LDAP.

Are there any documentations or blogs about it as to what the default endpoints are or what the API looks like or does it even talk in SOAP? or can you please shed some light on how to connect to Active Directory Web Services? or just where to find out the WSDL?

I googled/binged around without any luck. The closest page I could get is http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd391908(WS.10).aspx 
However, it doesn't tell me where and how to connect to the web service.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverDS/thread/fcdb56de-2422-49ed-a7c1-093fa9542c60/ and the answer from MSFT Moderator "As far as I know, ADWS doesn't support the HTTP-Binding."

Comment: But the post was created on October 02, 2009 which is a year ago.