# Active directory ADWS WSDL vs C# implementation

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, sharepoint, active-directory

So I'm trying to find a "Best" way to interact(**create a interface**) with Active Directory **read/write** mode.  So I'm deciding between this two aproaches:

1. Try and use the ADWS.
2. C# Implementation.

Apparently for ADWS is not [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966918/active-directory-web-services-adws-sdk) [easy](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/fcdb56de-2422-49ed-a7c1-093fa9542c60/adws-with-http-binding-and-access-from-a-java-client?forum=winserverDS) even though there is a full [WSDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd304094.aspx) I'v not been able to locate it, to try to do some test via SOAPui...

Now fort the C# Implementation there are [few](http://samirvaidya.blogspot.com/2012/06/using-active-directory-web-services-in.html) [implementations](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C) 
but still I'm not sure if its 100% doable to have full READ/WRITE to AD i.e. creating accounts users, query for users info, etc. from lets say REST WS.

So My questions are

1. Is there a way of getting a WSDL from the AD server so that I can use that as a starting point? ( I don't want to get me into PowerShell stuff or the like)
2. Are there any good articles for the latest versions C# ,libs, etc... to help me implement this?
3. Is there a better way of doing this?

As an example This is what we're trying to do:

**Scenario 1:**

1. Create a Web Service (INTERFACE) that expose AD information
2. The Web Service could be REST or SOAP
3. The WS should read/Query/Write the AD
4. Any Application inside the network can consume the WS

**Scenario 2** (What we currently plan to do):

1. Sharepoint Reads AD Information
2. Job should copy AD to DB
3. Applications can read this data
4. There should exist some replication between the DB and AD

Any suggestions will be more than welcome

[image: This is what I'm trying to do]

I'm Using server 2008R2 ,Sharepoint foundations 2010

Comment: We did several apps that work on AD with 50k+ users. The AD is addressed from C#. Take a look here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C If you have specific questions, ask again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is related to your [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27663157/active-directory-exchange-sharepoint-via-rest?rq=1) question which mentioned Exchange.

My personal suggestion is to host a WCF service in IIS.  You can set this service up to do whatever you want to suite your needs for the apps accessing it.  You can probably do most of what you need to do through the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement namespace when it comes to User and Groups.

System.DirectoryServices will give you more granular control at the cost of more work.  However, it is a little easier and reading and writing from/to custom attributes here.

If you're going to interact with Exchange 2010 you'll need to mess with Powershell.  And you could use Powershell to do core AD work as well.

And of course if you're going to write your own web service you *could* make it REST.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/gg145037%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is a link to MSDN with info about System.DirectoryServices and the various namespaces.  I personally find AD to be a lot of fun to work with.  There are many ways to do the same thing in it so I don't think there's one right answer for you.  Go with what you're comfortable with or challenge yourself to do something new!